# Azure Ad pricing with externals and multi-tenant users

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

Let's say I have a company of 100 employees/users in its Azure AD Premium P1.
This company has 100 monthly active external users in its Azure AD.
This company has some SaS multitenant applications(app registrations) which are used by 1000 monthly active users from different companies who have their own Azure Ad subscription.

For 100 users from the company's Azure AD Premium P1 applies pricing $6 per user/month.
For 1100 users(100 externals and 1000 from other Azure Ad subscriptions who use the multi-tenant apps) apply the MAU pricing - First 50,000 MAU $0/Monthly Active Users.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you don't pay anything for the users that are not represented as users in your tenant.
Only for the ones that sign in against your tenant.
If you publish a multi-tenant app, those users will log in against their Azure AD tenant.

On the other hand if you have an internal application (single-tenant) and you also allow partners to access it, those would count as external users in your tenant.

Comment: Thank you.

"On the other hand if you have an internal application (single-tenant) and you also allow partners to access it, those would count as external users in your tenant."

And for these external users in my tenant, using an internal application (single-tenant) this pricing model applies: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/

Comment: That's correct.